# How can I use a different `baseDirectory` for each test in sbt?

Tags: sbt

In my `build.sbt` file I have:

```
fork := true
//baseDirectory := ???
```

I would like to set `baseDirectory` above, commented, to a different folder for each test. To be more specific, ideally I would like a different folder for every fork.

Example, if I have `Class1Test`, `Class2Test`, `Class3Test`, the following final structure would work for me:

- When running `Class1Test`, baseDirectory would be `baseDirectory / tests / class1`
- When running `Class2Test`, baseDirectory would be `baseDirectory / tests / class2`
- When running `Class3Test`, baseDirectory would be `baseDirectory / tests / class3`

How can I achieve that?